# How can I run a shell script containing sudo commands from a PHP web page?

Tags: bash, permissions, apache2, sudo, php

I have a php file that executes a shell script:

```php
<?php
  echo exec('/var/www/html/disable.sh');
?>
```

The `disable.sh` file contains:

```bsh
sudo cp /var/www/html/1.cfg /var/www/html/2.cfg
```

When I run it manually through ssh as root user, using

```bsh
php /var/www/html/disable.php
```

the script works fine, but when I run it by visiting the page in my browser, it is not working.

I tried to edit the `sudoers` files and add:

```
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/a.sh
```

but that is not working either.

How can I run a shell script containing sudo commands from a PHP web page?

Comment: It's not a good idea to run services as the root user, especially those exposed to a network interface (ie: PHP).  There are many examples of how to run `bash` from `php`.  You will probably benefit from learning more about the system, user permissions, and how to securely run PHP before moving forward.  It will be hard to answer your question with so much seemingly wrong.  Don't be discouraged, though.  Work on getting everything set up and come back to run your `bash` file once you see everything else working together properly.